Old Russian animation about red-haired girl raised by witch who has adventures and tricks a three-headed dragon
I'm trying to find this seemingly really old Russian animated movie about a red headed little girl who was brought to a witch by a stork as a baby and is raised by the witch and these other creatures (a chubby character that has these 'nature' powers, a tall dark prince creature, and a female character made of hay...?). 
The girl has these big bright eyes and short red hair and goes on this adventure and near the climax she goes to this huge magical tree at night (it's covered in large chains) and has to trick this three-headed dragon so she can get something (I think a pearl?) to cure her dying grandmother (the witch that is raising her). In the end she is turned back into a baby and given to a human couple by a stork. 
EDIT I'm not sure that it was a stork that delivered the baby, it could've been the wind. But I know something did. 

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Are there any other plot details you remember? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title

Baba Yaga and Others (original title Бабка Ёжка и Другие) from 2006 fits the description.

The story of a little girl who is brought by a stork to a dense forest and lives with Russian fairy-tale characters: Baba Yaga (witch), Leshy (character with nature powers), Kikimora (female made of hay), and Koschei (dark prince).

I didn't see it, but the whole movie is available on YouTube. The girl is red-haired and dragon is also there.

